# Cannot convert value "Year" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: powershell

code -

```
# Get current Year and Month
param ([Int]$Year, [Int]$Month, [String]$Environment, [String]$Report, [String]$Username, [String]$Password)

function Get-DaysOfMonth {
    Param ([Int]$Year, [Int]$Month)
    $MonthDays = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    1..([datetime]::DaysInMonth($Year, $Month)) |
        ForEach-Object {
           $Day = ([datetime]::ParseExact("$_/$Month/$Year", "d/M/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString("dd")
           $MonthDays.Add($Day)
        }
    return $MonthDays
}

Write-Host "The Year Selected is: " + [String]$Year
Write-Host "The Month Selected is: " + [String]$Month
Write-Host "The Environment Selected is: $Environment"
Write-Host "The Report Generated is: $Report"
Write-Host "Export Generating as User: $Username"

$Days = Get-DaysOfMonth -Year $Year -Month $Month
```

When running I get the following traceback:

```
Cannot process argument 
transformation on parameter 'Year'. Cannot convert value "Year" to type 
"System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [myscript.ps1], ParentContai 
   nsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,myscript 
   .ps1
```

Seems it's having an issue converting my Integer variable as a String.  How do I fix that?

I'm running the script by the following command

```
myscript.ps1 -Year 2018 -Month 02 -Environment PROD -Report event -Username myacct -Password mypass
```

Comment: It's telling you you're passing the string `Year` (as in `Y`, `e`, `a`, `r`) as a parameter value somewhere, as opposed to an actual year. Check for a missing `$` (the error doesn't appear to be in this code snippet).

Comment: You never call the function Get-DaysOfMonth. I just ran this script and it runs fine for me. So maybe its happening before this script

Comment: I updated the question to include the last line I forgot to copy as well as the full command I'm running from myscript.ps1 on the commandline.

Comment: @ArcSet I've updated with the commandline being called.

Comment: found the problem it's my configuration in pycharm.  Running from Powershell prompt works fine.  investigating my pycharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There still is a problem with your `Write-Host` commands.

It runs here but outputs:

```
The Year Selected is:  + [String]2018
The Month Selected is:  + [String]2
The Environment Selected is: PROD
The Report Generated is: event
Export Generating as User: myacct
```

One way to solve this is to use a string format operator:

```
"The Year Selected is: {0}`nThe Month Selected is: {1}`nThe Environment Selected is: {2}`nThe Report Generated is: {3}`nExport Generating as User: {4}" -f $Year,$Month,$Environment,$Report,$Username
```

---

```
The Year Selected is: 2018
The Month Selected is: 2
The Environment Selected is: PROD
The Report Generated is: event
Export Generating as User: myacct
```

Comment: thnx @LotPings!  Just wanted to add that in your solving with the format operator ensure you put the () around the Write-Host command.  ie. `Write-Host("The Year Selected is: {0}" -f $Year)`